# Excel VBA "Object variable or With block variable not set "

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Sub CheckDates()

bAlarm = False

i = 1
Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(row_header, i).Value = ""
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(row_header, i).Value = searchText Then
        col = i
        Exit Do
    End If
i = i + 1
Loop

i = 1
Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(row_header, i).Value = ""
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(row_header, i).Value = searchNameText Then
        col_name = i
        Exit Do
    End If
i = i + 1
Loop

If col = 0 Then
    MsgBox searchText & " basliklar arasinda bulunamadi"
    Exit Sub
Else
    N = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = row_header + 1 To N
        If isInDateRange(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, col).Value) Then
            With UserForm1.ListBox1
                .AddItem
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 0) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, col_name).Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, col).Value
            End With
            bAlarm = True
        End If
    Next i
End If

If bAlarm = True Then
    UserForm1.Show
End If
```

I am getting the `Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)` error on the line with `Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(row_header, i).Value = ""`. When I debug I can see that `hprlink.Range` does have a value. Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is code missing from your question I think the issue is indeed in:

```
Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(row_header, i).Value = ""
```

As far as I can tell, `row_header` is empty at this point, so will likely be resolving to:

```
Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells( 0, 1).Value = ""
```

There is no row 0, so you get your error.

Put a value in `row_header` (perhaps `1` - I can't see your sheet?) before you start your loops to locate the field.

Furthermore, you might want to check out `WorksheetFunction.Match` as it will do the same thing your first two loops are doing with just one line.

Finally, you probably should stop referring to `ActiveSheet` all the time throughout your sub, either use a `With` block or `Set` an object at the start to refer to.